# Как определить существует ли файл с помощью Python?

Tags: python, файлы, текстовые-файлы

Суть программы:

Файл открывается и из него записываются переменные.

```py
with open(u"/storage/emulated/0/PyTycoon/Variables.txt", "r") as v:
    a = v.read().split("\n")
money = int(a[0])
s1 = int(a[1])
s2 = int(a[2])
s3 = int(a[3])
L = int(a[4])
```

Содержимое файла **Variables.txt**:

```
0
5
1000
10000
1
```

Вопрос:

Как сделать так, чтобы, когда пайтон определял, что файла нет, создавал его со значениями выше?

Comment: почитать чуток о режимах открытия файлов. С какими, кстати, "значениями выше" должен создаваться файл?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для проверки наличия файла лучше использовать именно методы, подобные `isfile`, а методы `exists` использовать нежелательно, так как если у вас будет одноимённая с файлом директория "qwe1.txt", то `exists` скажет вам, что такое имя на диске есть, и вы решите, что это файл, а не папка.

Для проверки есть две библиотеки: `os` и `pathlib`. Так же можно проверить, выполнив чтение в блоке `try`, например, основные методы проверок наличия файла выглядят так:

```py
file = 'qwe1.txt'

import os  # 1
print(os.path.isfile(file))  # False - файла нет

import pathlib  # 2
print(pathlib.Path(file).is_file())  # False - файла нет

try:  # 3
    open(file).read()
except (FileNotFoundError, PermissionError):
    print('файла нет')
else:
    print('файл есть')
```

Если вы уверены, что каталога, одноименного с файлом, быть не может, то можно добавить эти:

```py
import os
print(os.path.exists(file))
print(os.access(file, os.R_OK))

import pathlib
print(pathlib.Path(file).exists())
```

Конкретно в этой задаче, это могло выглядеть так:

```py
import pathlib

file = pathlib.Path('qwe.txt')
if file.is_file():
    money, s1, s2, s3, L = map(int, file.open().readlines())
else:
    d = money, s1, s2, s3, L = [0, 5, 1000, 10000, 1]
    file.write_text('\n'.join(map(str, d)))

print(money, s1, s2, s3, L)
```

Answer (score 5):

Проверить, существует ли файл можно через:

```py
os.path.exists(path)
```

Чтобы записать в файл, которого не существует (т.е. файл будет создан), нужно открыть его с ключами `a+` или `w+`.

Если вам нужно записать в файл переменные "по умолчанию", то сначала проверьте его наличие, и, если он отсутствует, откройте файл для записи с одним из указанных ключей.